# Can I access methods from another object without using $GLOBALS or dependency injection?

Tags: php, oop, methods

Here's my situation: I have a user class with functions like `get_friends_list()` and `get_last_visit()`. Then I have a `$db` object which is a database framework, it has functions like `insert()` and `select()`.

The reason why I don't want to have to use dependency injection is that my `$db` object has things like a query counter which is updated every time a query is executed. Dependency injection would create a new `$db` object so I wouldn't be able to keep track of these things because there would be a whole new object.

In short, is there a way of achieving this:

```
class user{
    public function get_last_visit(){
        return $GLOBALS['db']->get(
            'users',
            'last_visit',
            'username' => $this->username
        );
    }
}
```

but without using the $GLOBALS variable which I've heard is bad practise.

Comment: Dependency injection **would not** create new instance. Please learn actually what it is and how it works, before making broad claims about it.

Comment: ... you could, you know, pass the actual handle into the function?

Answer (score 2):

Dependency Injection would not create a new object, unless you `clone` it explicitly (which you don't).

Basically: **Use Dependency Injection**.

Comment: You mean I can add `function __construct($db){ $this->db = $db;}` to my user class and then do `$user = new user($db);`, and then when I call `$user->get_friends_list();` it will use the same instance of `$db`?

Comment: Well, that's something new that I've learned, I'd always thought it would create a new instance. :) Thank you.